# How to sort files in linux by number?

Tags: python, linux

My program reads in the number parsed from the file name. I want it to be ordered exactly how it is, but, in this example, list as 500, 4000, 7000. How should my naming convention look to achieve this? That is, when I have incrementing numbers, it lists it from smallest to highest.

What I really want is for it to sort by rank, (which here starts at zero), then sorts it by the incrementing numbers.. 500, 5000, 7000.

[image]

## DESIRED OUTPUT

```
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-7000.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-7000.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-7000.txt
```

## Relevant Code

```
for filenamelogs in sorted(os.listdir(log_directory)):
            for each_line in filenamelogs:
                   #various file parsing activity
```

I'm appending the data file-by-file to various arrays. Unfortunately, this is terrible to me if I can't sort the file reads in the order requested. Maybe my question is veered toward developing a custom method to read in files under the sorting constraints I provide.

Comment: if your numbers can't go over 9999, you could use 0500 instead of 500

Comment: They can exceed that number. This number represent microseconds and can go up to 10 hours.

Comment: If your program is reading the strings, it can parse them however it likes.  Your question makes very little sense to me. Are you asking about sorting the output of `ls`?

Comment: Unclear. What is this display you are showing ? It doesnt look like `ls -l` so it's the output of your program ? If yes, I assume python (tag), but then, can you show some related code ? Please clarify question and use case.

Comment: I'm starting to realize this isn't really coded up in my program as I intended, but it reads in each file, file-by-file. However, if I could get it to read in the files in this type of order, I would be able to have my sorting done for me. I'm not sure how I get the program to read in under this type of sorting requirement.

Comment: @kebs The output image is the result of using tree and yes it is the same as ls -1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a comment on a blog linked in a [blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/):

```
>>> import re
>>> def sort_nicely(l):
...     """
...     Sort the given list in the way that humans expect. Modifies the original list.
...     """
...     convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
...     alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
...     l.sort(key=alphanum_key)
...
>>> mylist = ['LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-500.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-4000.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-7000.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-500.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-4000.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-7000.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-500.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-4000.txt',
... 'LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-7000.txt']
>>> sort_nicely(mylist)
>>> print(*mylist, sep='\n')
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-0-die-10-delay-7000.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-1-die-10-delay-7000.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-500.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-4000.txt
LOG-rank-2-die-10-delay-7000.txt
```

To `return` a new, sorted `list` instead of modifying the original one in place:

```
>>> def sort_nicely(l):
...     """
...     Sort the given list in the way that humans expect. Returns a new list.
...     """
...     convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
...     alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
...     return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)
...
>>> newlist = sort_nicely(mylist)
>>> print(*newlist, sep='\n')
```

Comment: You have no idea the appreciation I have to this comment right now. I've spent a week on this program and this is my last little bug ruining me. Will implement now and see the results.

Comment: What should I return from the sort_nicely function to output the sorted list?

Comment: `list.sort()` modifies the original `list`. If you want it to `return` a new `list`, change that line to `return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)`. You'll then have to save a reference with `newlist = sort_nicely(mylist)` and print that new `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that last comment is very useful and relevant. Why not add it to your answer for future readers?